# Class or interface Expected android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android studio.
I've imported project in android studio and without any changes I'm getting the error.
'Class or interface Expected'
Can anyone help me out?

```
class this.cls0
    implements android.view.istener
{

    final LyricsEdit this$0;

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        mDismissMethod = 1;
        mLyrics = mEditLyrics.getText().toString();
        dismiss();
    }

    ()
    {
        this$0 = LyricsEdit.this;
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this source code? This is not valid Java; `class this.cls0` is not valid Java syntax, and the () thing below also isn't.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to handle Click event you should try this:

```
_loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Some method to do...
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help.